# Select only unique rows with INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry, not quite sure how to word this.

There are two database tables, `store_locations` and `store_diagnostics`.

`store_locations` holds static information about the store, such as `zip_code`, `StoreId` and a few other things. While `store_diagnostics` holds diagnostic data and stats on each store location, such as `total_sold`, `total_revenue`, etc.

New entries are entered into `store_diagnostics` every hour or so via a cron job that checks for total sales, etc. The only issue on my behalf is that instead of updating previously existing rows, a new row is created for each time the cron job runs so that sales from this week can be compared to last week etc.

My current query works, but it fetches multiple entries for the same store. Ideally, I'd like to only fetch the latest `store_diagnostics` row for the given `StoreId` and order them by the `created` field descending so I get the last created row for that particular store.

Here is my existing query:

```
SELECT
  locations.* ,
  location_stats.total_sold ,
  location_stats.total_moved_to ,
  location_stats.total_moved_from ,
  location_stats.total_revenue ,
  location_stats.created
FROM store_locations locations
  INNER JOIN
    store_diagnostics location_stats
  ON
    locations.StoreId = location_stats.StoreId
ORDER BY location_stats.created DESC , location_stats.total_sold DESC
```

As you can see, I'd like to only fetch one result per `StoreId` and I'd like that to be fetched after ordering the rows by the `created` column in `DESC` order.

The `location_stats.total_sold` is the sorting method I'd like to be used on all the results, so that all the unique stores are sorted by their total amount of items sold.

I am sorry if this is unclear, I hope I have explained it sufficiently.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a where clause that filters based on the maximum created which would be the top value if sorted in descending order.  The overall sort order was changed to the total_sold as indicated in the problem description.  Note if your cron job generates new rows faster than the precision of created, you'll get duplicates.  I'm assuming it doesn't.  If you have an identity as the PK in store_diagnostics, I'd take the max of it rather than created.

Option 1:  Use a correlated subquery

```
SELECT
  locations.* ,
  location_stats.total_sold ,
  location_stats.total_moved_to ,
  location_stats.total_moved_from ,
  location_stats.total_revenue ,
  location_stats.created
FROM store_locations locations
  INNER JOIN store_diagnostics location_stats ON locations.StoreId = location_stats.StoreId
WHERE location_stats.created = (select max(created) from store_diagnostics where stored_id = locations.stored_id)
ORDER BY location_stats.total_sold DESC
```

Option 2:  Join to a groupby

```
SELECT
  locations.* ,
  location_stats.total_sold ,
  location_stats.total_moved_to ,
  location_stats.total_moved_from ,
  location_stats.total_revenue ,
  location_stats.created
FROM store_locations locations
  INNER JOIN store_diagnostics location_stats ON locations.StoreId = location_stats.StoreId
  INNER JOIN (select store_id, max(created) created from stored_diagnostics group by store_id) mx on locations.store_id = mx.stored_id and location_stats.created = mx.created
ORDER BY location_stats.total_sold DESC
```

Comment: I think that might work, but it's probably one of the worst performing ways to do it; since you're using a correlated subquery, it'll be running a separate aggregating query over `store_diagnostics` for every entry in `store_diagnostics`. Barring undocumented optimizer tricks, if a location has 100 entries, it will look for the last entry for that location 100 separate times to throw away 99 of those entries.

Comment: @Uueerdo Agreed.  Added another option.